# UWP XAML ListView.ItemTemplate não segue o espaçamento de colunas definido em ListView.HeaderTemplate

Tags: xaml, uwp

Estou escrevendo um app com a `ListView` definida abaixo:

```
<ListView x:Name="TodosRecibos">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="12" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Recibo" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Data" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Tomador" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Serviço" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Valor" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="ListaRecibos" x:DataType="data:Recibo">
                    <Grid Height="48" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ReciboId}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind ReciboId}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind ServicoData}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind TomadorNome}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind ServicoDescricao}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{x:Bind ServicoValor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Esperava que os itens na `ListView` seguissem o espaçamento de colunas definidas em `ListView.HeaderTemplate`, idênticas em `ListView.ItemsTemplate`. Porém, ao executar, os itens ficam assim:

[image: Disposição de itens numa ListView que não segue o espaçamento de colunas]

Como posso fazer para que os itens na `ListView` se alinhem corretamente às colunas?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza é o estilo padrão, sem modificações.

Comment: Procurei na API por este atributo, mas só o encontrei no Xamarin. De qualquer forma, encontrei uma solução.

Comment: Sim, eu achei que os componentes do UWP era o mesmo usado no Xamarin.Forms. Deve ser o mesmo do WPF. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nesta Pergunta do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775116/why-do-listview-headertemplate-and-listview-itemtemplate-uwp-xaml-display-diff) há uma solução:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

O respondente explica que, por padrão, `ListViewITem` não estica seu conteúdo, o que é conseguido com o código XAML acima.